# How to select counts from different tables with foreign keys?

Tags: mysql, sql, postgresql

```
city
----------------------
id    city_name
1     Pune
2     Mumbai
3     Banglore

Branches
----------------------
id    branch_name     city_id
1     Magarpatta      1
2     Wagholi         1
3     Kurla           2
4     CST             2
5     Thane           2
6     Anekal          3

Employees
----------------------
id    employee_name   city_id
1     Arun            1
2     Varun           1
3     Mahesh          2
4     Umesh           2
5     Prakash         1
6     Kedar           3

Expected result
-----------------------------
id(city) city_name  No_of_Branch  no_of_employee
1        Pune       2             3
2        Mumbai     3             2
3        Banglore   1             1
```

Can I get above result in single Query?
Can I Use Crosstab in this scenario? How?

Comment: Show us what have you tried so far. We are not here to do your homework / task. -1 from me.

Answer (score 1):

```
    SELECT c.*, count(DISTINCT b.id) AS No_of_Branch, count(DISTINCT e.id) AS no_of_employee
       FROM city c 
         LEFT JOIN branches  b ON (b.city_id=c.id)
         LEFT JOIN employees e ON (e.city_id=c.id)
    GROUP BY c.id
```

Or

```
    SELECT c.*, 
       (SELECT count(b.id) FROM branches  b WHERE b.city_id=c.id) AS No_of_Branch, 
       (SELECT count(e.id) FROM employees e WHERE e.city_id=c.id) AS no_of_employee
   FROM city c
```

Comment: @ Eugene!
thanks for replay, but this doesnt return the correct results while applying second join it creates join on all the data within first join.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
 SELECT c.id, c.city_name,
        COUNT(b.id) AS No_of_Branch, 
        no_of_employee
 FROM city c 
 LEFT JOIN branches b ON b.city_id = c.id
 LEFT JOIN (
   SELECT city_id, COUNT(e.id) AS no_of_employee
   FROM employees AS e
   GROUP BY e.city_id
 ) AS e_grp  ON e_grp.city_id = c.id
 GROUP BY c.id, c.city_name
```

The trick here is to use a derived table containing the count of employees per `city_id`. I you just join all tables together you will end up with duplicate counts of employees.

[**Demo here**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/09459/4)